# Call parent page's method from a user control

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

I have a user control which is displayed as a popup. I need to call a method from its parent page when this user control is dismissed by user. How can I do that?

I tried calling it in 'unloaded' event of popup but I cannot access the parent page's methods from the control...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the currently used instance of the parent page into the popup. That way, you can access the public methods the parent page has.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you should use an event, no?  Add an event handler in the parent window.  Use either a predefined event in the user control (for example, Closed) or program your own event in the user control:

```
parentWindowMethod()
{
  MyUserControl myUserControl = new MyUserControl();
  myUserControl.event += this.userControlDismisseed;
  ...
}

userControlDismissed(...)
{
  ...
}
```